# Am I solving this constrained variational problem correctly?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, constraints, euler-lagrange-equation

I have the following **constrained calculus of variations problem** (that I came up with myself):

Find the extremals of $$J(y)=\int_a^b y^2(x)+y'^2(x)dx, \text{ subject to } y(a)=y_a,y(b)=y_b, \text{ and }\int_a^b y(x)dx=C$$

For some $a, b$.

**Solution:**
The Euler lagrange equations give:

$$y''(x)=y(x)+\lambda$$
Solving this gives the general solution:
$$y(x)=Ae^x-Be^{-x}-\lambda$$

Now solving for $A,B$ gives:

$$A=\frac{(y_a+\lambda)e^{-a}-(y_b+\lambda)e^{-2a}}{1-e^{b-2a}}$$

$$B=\frac{(y_a+\lambda)e^{2b}-(y_b+\lambda)e^b}{1-e^{2b-a}}$$

Now the constraint becomes: 
$$\int_a^by(x)dx=Ae^x+Be^{-x}-\lambda x\bigg |_a^b=A(e^b-e^a)+B(e^{-b}-e^{-a})-\lambda(b-a)=C$$

**Now for simplicity:** 
Assume $a=0,b=1,y_a=y_b=0$.

Then $A=0$,j $B=-\lambda \alpha$, with $\alpha =\frac{e^2-e}{e^2-1}$ and the constraint reduces to: 
$$\lambda(-\frac \alpha e+\alpha -1)=C$$
Here, simplifying the factor of $\lambda$ gives $$\lambda \cdot 0 = C$$

---

**Now my questions:**

**Firstly**, this is the first constrained variational problem I've tried to solve. Is my approach correct?

**Secondly**, What is the conclusion that we can draw from the final equation? It does not give a value for $\lambda$. Does this mean that there is no solution? or that all curves that satisfy the constraint are solutions? or something else?

Answer (score 1):

1. (In this answer, we assume that $a\neq b$. By renaming if necessary, we may assume that $a<b$.)

   OP's approach is correct in principle, but his result (v1) cannot be right. OP must have made a mistake somewhere in his algebra. The coefficient in front $\lambda$ in the integral $\int_a^b \!\mathrm{d}x~y(x)$ over the solution cannot vanish.
2. While nothing can replace a mathematical proof, it is always good to have some intuition for what the answer could or should be. We leave it to OP to find his mistake, but below is a physical argument why his result (v1) cannot be right.

   In the physics model from Newtonian point mechanics, $x$ is time; $y$ is position; $y^{\prime}$ is velocity; the mass $m=1$; the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ is a constraint force that imposes the constraint; and $\frac{C}{b-a}$ is an average position.

   OP's [action functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)#Action_.28functional.29) reads (up to normalization)
   $$ J[y]~:=~\frac{1}{2}\int_a^b \!\mathrm{d}x~(y^{\prime 2}(x)+ y^2(x))+ \lambda\left(\int_a^b \!\mathrm{d}x~y(x) -C\right). \tag{1}$$
   To derive the [EL eq.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) for $y$ (but not $\lambda$!) we can drop the last term, and use the following action functional instead
   $$ S[y]~:=~\int_a^b \!\mathrm{d}x~\{\frac{1}{2}y^{\prime 2}(x) -V(y(x))\}, \tag{2}$$
   where 
   $$V(y)~:=~-\left(\frac{y}{2}+\lambda\right)y \tag{3}$$
   is an unstable quadratic potential. The EL eq. for $y$ is just Newton's 2nd law:
   $$ y^{\prime\prime}~=~-\frac{dV}{dy}~=~y+\lambda. \tag{4}$$
   While $\lambda$ is a Lagrange multiplier in the action functional (1), it can be viewed as a constant external force in the action functional (2). Regardless of the boundary conditions, by tuning the external force $\lambda$ any way we please, e.g. very big, the average position $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b \!\mathrm{d}x~y(x)$ of the solution must be affected, contradicting OP's result (v1).